# Git Bash terminal in Eclipse on MS Windows

Tags: eclipse, git

I have two different laptops running MS Windows and noticed on one laptop there was a Git Bash option for a new terminal window in the Terminal view in Eclipse, while it was not available on the other laptop.

After a little trial and error, I was able to determine the Git Bash option is only available if the git cli client from https://git-scm.com is installed.

I like to be able to run git from the command line in Eclipse without having to switch windows. Hope this helps someone trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Open A Terminal icon to open up Git Bash if Git Bash is already installed on your Windows machine.

[image]

**Update:**
Add Gitbash terminal to Eclipse:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Install this plugin on Eclipse Marketplace:

**TM Terminal**
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal

After that, go to Window -> Preferences -> Terminal -> Local Terminal and add a entry with full path where Git Bash executable (bash.exe) was installed.

Then you can open Git Bash pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.